# Equivalence testing vs ANOVA post hoc tests

Tags: post-hoc, equivalence

How is statistical equivalence testing different from post hoc tests done after ANOVA?

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalence testing"?

Comment: @chl "equivalence testing" is a thing. See my answer.

Comment: @Alexis I'm aware of TOST or statistical tests of non-inferiority in randomized clinical trials. I thought it would be clearer if the OP could clarify in plain English what he/she wants to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *post hoc* tests following an ANOVA are **pairwise *t* tests for mean difference**. They have null hypotheses that the population means are equal (alternatively that the difference in population means is zero). Also, there are some *post hoc* details like pooled variance and multiple comparisons adjustments. We can set those aside, as they are largely irrelevant to your question.

By contrast, tests for equivalence (which *could* be, but are not necessarily *post hoc* tests following an ANOVA), have null hypotheses that the population means are different by at least some researcher-defined amount. You might get something out of reading the [tost tag description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info).

One can combine the inferences from difference and equivalence tests, as I point out in my question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95667/intuitive-explanation-of-differences-between-tost-and-ump-tests-for-equivalence).

Comment: So you suggest equivalence testing to infer which pairs did not contribute to the global difference revealed by an ANOVA test? Interesting thought! In the end it's a completely different approach to the same interpretation "pairs A and B contribute to the revealed global difference, but pairs C and D are to similar". But I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: That's a fair point. Mostly, I was trying to spell out the differences between *post hoc* tests for difference, and equivalence tests. :)